# send_file for a tempfile in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to use Sinatra's built-in [`send_file`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sending%20Files) command  but it doesn't seem to be working for tempfiles.

I basically do the following to zip an album of mp3s:

```
get '/example' do
  songs = ...
  file_name = "zip_test.zip"
  t = Tempfile.new(['temp_zip', '.zip'])
  # t = File.new("testfile.zip", "w")
  Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |z|
    songs.each do |song|
      name = song.name
      name += ".mp3" unless name.end_with?(".mp3")
      z.put_next_entry(name)
      z.print(open(song.url) {|f| f.read })
      p song.name + ' added to file'
    end
  end
  p t.path
  p t.size

  send_file t.path, :type => 'application/zip',
                         :disposition => 'attachment',
                         :filename => file_name,
                          :stream => false
  t.close
  t.unlink
end
```

When I use `t = File.new(...)` things work as expected, but I don't want to use `File` as it will have concurrency problems.

When I use `t = Tempfile.new(...)`, I get:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: The file identified by body.to_path does not exist`
```

---

Edit: It looks like part of the problem is that I'm sending multiple files. If I just send one song, the Tempfile system works as well.

Comment: What happens if you use a pre-built zip file that has multiple files in it, instead of using `Zip::ZipOutputStream.open`…? Also, [send_file sends a halt](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L308) so the `t.close` and `t.unlink` aren't needed (and the file system should take care of this for you anyway).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a typo in one of your song-names, or maybe a slash in one of the last parts of song.url? I [adopted your code](https://github.com/onli/music-streamer/blob/master/server.rb#L160) and if all the songs exist, sending the zip as a tempfile works perfectly fine.